# Start With Specified Image and Randomize on Click

Tags: html

I'd like to have a specific image display, and allow users to click on it and the image changes, kind of like a mouseover effect. However, I want it to show a random image from a set list. It'd happen once per page refresh, and be done. I'd prefer it not be reversible.

What I'm using it for is a random card draw with images. I start with the back of the card, and have many possibilities to show up when clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a script to randomize an image on the page with each refresh, and some basic mouseover HTML. What I need is almost like a hybrid of the two, except with clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic code you would need as far as I understand

```
<img src="img/BackOfCard.jpg" onClick="Randomize(this)" />
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="onlyOnce">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Randomize(obj) {
  onlyOnce = document.getElementById("onlyOnce");
  if (onlyOnce.value=="1") {
    var n = Math.round((100*Math.random())+0.5);
    var urls = ["url1.png","url2.png","and so on"];
    obj.src = urls[n];
    onlyOnce.value="0";
  }
}
</script>
```

This assumes that you have a folder called "img" with the back of card image and all the card faces stored there.  The card faces will be stored in the format Ace = 1.jpg, 2 = 2.jpg, 3 = 3.jpg, King = 13.jpg and so on.

Comment: That looks good, but I have a couple of issues: First, my set of cards is saved as 1.png, 2.png, etc., but I have about 100 of them. They aren't traditional numbers and face cards. Additionally, I must host online for this, and I cannot create an folder with the specified cards. I will need something that allows me to input each and every URL (yes, it'll be a royal pain).

Comment: My next issue is that the SRC when showing the second images is no longer name1.png, it's a long address followed by that name. Do this line need changing?  obj.src = urls[n];

Comment: Ok, I made the script work, but I'm now using two of them on the same page - let's call them card A and B. Both cards are only drawing from selections of B, and I can only click one or the other. I need to be able to work both.

Comment: Additionally, I'd like to do it more than once in some cases. How do I edit the code to do that?